# returning actual Height and Width to wpf rectangle after dynamic change

Tags: c#, wpf, height, width, rectangles

I have an app with the main window which contains a rectangle and a button that leads to another window in which the user enters information. After entering info, user clicks on a button and it returns him to the main window and changes the size accordingly. What I am trying to achieve is to return the ActualHeight and ActualWidth to the rectangle if a user presses the button in the main window again, kind of a refresh of rectangle.
All the code is in the Main Window Button click event. If you need any specific information about the code, i will gladly give it to you.

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Questionnaire q = new Questionnaire();
        q.ShowDialog();

var size = q.textBoxNumberOfEmployees.Text;

        if (int.Parse(size) > 5 && int.Parse(size) < 15)
        {
            Rect1.Height = Rect1.ActualHeight - 10;
            Rect1.Width = Rect1.ActualWidth - 5;
        }

        else if (int.Parse(size) > 15 && int.Parse(size) < 30)
        {
            Rect1.Height = Rect1.ActualHeight - 15;
            Rect1.Width = Rect1.ActualWidth - 10;
        }
        else if (int.Parse(size) > 30 && int.Parse(size) < 100)
        {
            Rect1.Height = Rect1.ActualHeight - 30;
            Rect1.Width = Rect1.ActualWidth - 15;
        }
        else
        {
            Rect1.Height = Rect1.ActualHeight;
            Rect1.Width = Rect1.ActualWidth;
        }
```

Comment: I'm gonna say that we need specific information about the code.

Comment: @Abion47 i have edited my question, added a code that could help

Comment: I think the most solid way to handle this type of code would be to use a model view controller pattern. Have a model assigned that stores the original values and resources such as animations, etc. Create a source class that interprets user input and sends the data to the Model class. Have the model update the view class that changes the button to whatever you would like. Sounds like a lot of work, but it pays off when it is all put together. A single model class can handle many UI elements, but I usually create one model class for each complex model. XAML and WINFORMS act as View objects.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting marked down, I will be more constructive on addressing your coding. You need to validate your data before storing it as a "var" and then just parsing it. int.TryParse(stringToParse, out int) is a great way to do that but you will need a  default value to fall back on if it fails. Now invalid data won't make it crash. Next, don't add fields and properties. This is bad coding... If you really want to learn coding and not just an easy answer check this post: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105352/why-should-i-use-an-mvc-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the original height and width of rectangle in variables in form load. Use those variables to make rectangle to original size bebore opening new window in button click.
 Following code goes at the top inside your form.

private int rect1width;
private int rect1height;

In your form__load you write this at the end.

rect1width = Rect1.ActualWidth;
rect1height = Rect1.ActualHeight;

In your button click code following code goes at top.

Rect1.Width = rect1width;
Rect1.Height = rect1height;

Comment: how would i store and use it?

Comment: Create two variables in your form and set values from rect's actualheight and actualwidth. These variables will be accessible across all code of your form as you are able to access Rect1 so you can use it in button click code. set rect.width and rect.height from them in your button click event.

Comment: this is the way to do it with small remark, ActualHeight and ActualWidth are doubles, so instead of private int just switch private double and it works like a charm!
Thank You

Answer (score -1):

Here is some seemingly long code, but it uses an MVC type design pattern and compounds with the state pattern. The only thing really missing to make it true MVC is Observers and observable interfaces that would subscribe to the Questionnaire.

```
public interface RectangleState
    {
        int myHeight { get; set; }
        int myWidth { get; set; }
    }
    public class RectangleModel
    {
        private static Rectangle Rect1;
        public RectangleModel(Rectangle rect1 )
        {
            Rect1 = rect1;
        }        
        private RectangleState state;
        public RectangleState State
        {
            get
            {
                return state;
            }
            set
            {
                state = value;
                ModifyState(value.myHeight, value.myWidth);
            }
        }
        private void ModifyState(int Height, int Width)
        {
            Rect1.Height = Height;
            Rect1.Width = Width;
        }
    }
    public class SmallState : RectangleState
    {
        public int myHeight { get; set; } = 20;
        public int myWidth { get; set; } = 80;
    }
    public class MediumState : RectangleState
    {
        public int myHeight { get; set; } = 25;
        public int myWidth { get; set; } = 90;
    }
    public class LargeState : RectangleState
    {
        public int myHeight { get; set; } = 35;
        public int myWidth { get; set; } = 120;
    }
    public class NormalState : RectangleState
    {
        public int myHeight { get; set; } = 30;
        public int myWidth { get; set; } = 100;
    }
```

Now all you need to do is plug in the conditions:

```
RectangleModel RM = new RectangleModel(myRectangle); // store this in your class as property;
            int size = 0;
            int.TryParse(q.textBoxNumberOfEmployees.Text, out size);
            if (size > 5 && size < 15)
            {
                RM.State = new SmallState();                
            }

            else if (size > 15 && size < 30)
            {
                RM.State = new MediumState();
            }
            else if (size > 30 && size < 100)
            {
                RM.State = new LargeState();
            }
            else
            {
                RM.State = new NormalState();
            }
```

If later you decide you want to change the default values on any of these you can change them. If you wish to add a new Rectangle shape or size you can add it. If you wish to create an adapter to further modify the rectangle, you can do so. This is a nice pattern. I know the answer looks overdone, but I think you will find it works solidly and is quite flexible when plugged into the code that accesses your questionaire.

Comment: this would be good except i got 6 rectangles and 5 ellipses to handle, so it would be kinda of a long process typing this code or even just copy pasting it. Don't get me wrong, I actually like this method and would use it if it was just 1 or 2,3 rectangles. But in my scenario i need something more practical!